# How to get all subversion and mercurial error code?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I have a project relate subversion and mercurial, I want to get all error code for my project.

I try to find on offical website of Subversion and Mercurail but not thing helpful. The website just mentions about common error when user uses.

Can you suggest to me anyway, to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Apache Subversion and Mercurial are both open-source, so you can easily find error codes / wordings if you do a little search.

Comment: I tried to check out the source of Apache, Subversion but files or folder relates error code not exist. Mercurial is not a public source code so I can't do anything

Comment: Its all opensource and is public. Take a deeper research.